# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "sarcasmo" e "ironía"? ¿O son sinónimos?

Tags: vocabulario

En la forma en que lo escucho usarse, siempre pensé que *ironía* se usaba para referirse a una situación contradictoria y *sarcasmo* era lo que uno usaba para querer decir lo contrario a lo que se mencionaba explícitamente, pero me encuentro con que en Inglés una definición (traducida al español) de *sarcasmo* es:

[Sarcasmo](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=xLHuXYWCJPi55OUPxqWq-As&q=sarcasm%20meaning&oq=sarcasm%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i70i249j0i22i30l9.200.2913..3094...0.0..0.327.3581.2-11j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0j0i10.sVVsaTXg4UU&ved=0ahUKEwiF9JeAt6nmAhX4HLkGHcaSCr8Q4dUDCAY&uact=5):

> El uso de ironía para burlarse o transmitir desprecio

y luego [Irony](https://www.google.com/search?ei=yLHuXcurNtq65OUP0dWw-A0&q=irony%20meaning&oq=irony%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67i70i249j0i22i30l9.6463.8017..8169...0.4..0.345.3436.2-9j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0j0i10.snvpsGSVEig&ved=0ahUKEwjLr56Ct6nmAhVaHbkGHdEqDN8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) traducido al español dice:

> noun
>
> 1. ironía
> 2. sarcasmo

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "sarcasmo" e "ironía"? ¿O son sinónimos?

Comment: Esto me ayudó a mí: https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/irony-satire-sarcasm/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los significados de las palabras en inglés no siempre son los mismos que los de las palabras similares en español.

En el Diccionario de la Lengua Española (DLE, RAE), [ironía](https://dle.rae.es/iron%C3%ADa) se define como "burla fina o disimulada", opcionalmente mediante el uso de una "expresión que da a entender lo contrario de lo que se dice".

La definición de la RAE para [sarcasmo](https://dle.rae.es/sarcasmo) me resulta sorprendente: "Burla sangrienta, ironía mordaz y cruel con que se ofende o maltrata a alguien o algo". La diferencia más importante es por tanto que el sarcasmo tiene mala intención, mientras que la ironía puede ser humorosa sin ser malintencionada.

Por esta razón se utiliza a veces el adjetivo *irónico* también para referirse a situaciones:

> Es irónico que muchos conductores de Fórmula 1 no tengan licencia de conducción

En este ejemplo, *sarcástico* no se puede utilizar porque las situaciones no pueden tener mala intención: solo las personas y sus comentarios pueden ser sarcásticos.

Answer (score 4):

**Ironía y sarcasmo aunque no son sinónimos están ligados,  en cuanto a que ambos usan la figura de transmitir el sentido contrario de lo que se dice**

**El sarcasmo es una forma de ironía, usado con una intencionalidad burlesca e insultante** (todo sarcasmo contiene ironía, pero no toda ironía equivale a un sarcasmo)

La palabra ironía—proveniente del griego εἰρωνεία (eirōneía), que significa ‘disimulo’ o ‘ignorancia fingida" —es una figura retórica de dar a entender algo expresando lo contrario de lo que se quiere decir o se piensa.

El uso de la ironía es un arte fino que tiene distintas formas (además del sarcasmo, como la [antifrasis, asteismo, carientismo, clenasmo, diasirmo, mímesis](https://www.retoricas.com/2009/06/3-ejemplos-de-ironia.html?m=1)).

Se asocia a una habilidad elegante y  sutil, con la que es posible traspasar resistencias, descolocar por la vía del absurdo, el humor inteligente que resalta lo grotesco, desproporcionado, poco importanteo o gracioso de situaciones, otras personas y uno mismo.

> Ejemplos: 
>   *comieron una comida etern sin principio ni fin* (por decir que no comieron nada)
>   *no debería procuparme por esa plata, sólo eran todos mis ahorros*

---

El sarcasmo, —con el disimulo, burlesco, de cargar un sentido opuesto al declamado— se caracteriza **por la intención hiriente, volcada sobre alguien con un tono agresivo, malicioso o mordaz** [ver definición](https://dle.rae.es/sarcasmo?m=form)

> *¡qué bueno tu perfume!¿cuanto tiempo has estado sumergido en él?*

La etimología  de sarcasmo remite a ese carácter hiriente

> [sarcasmo](https://dle.rae.es/sarcasmo?m=form) 
>   del latín *sarcasmus* y éste, derivado del griego *sarkasmós*, que se formó, a su vez, a partir del verbo *sarkázein* ‘desollar’, (con origen en *sarx*, *sarkós* ‘carne’)

Comment: La ironia no es solamente el como decir las cosas, si no el estudio de los hechos que se contraponen y puede que se contradigan, ejemplos: "si quieres paz, prepárate para la guerra"

Comment: Cierto. La definición es más amplia. Hay también  ironías.de situación, como la `de un conductor de una ambulancia que atropella a la víctima que se supone debería  ayudar`

Comment: Hay tres tipos de ironía: **Verbal** ("gracias por la multa, es lo que me hacía falta"); **Situacional** (una estación de bomberos se quema); **Dramática** (Romeo piensa que Julieta está muerta)

Answer (score 0):

Consultado en el DLE [**Ironía**](https://dle.rae.es/iron%C3%ADa?m=form) y [**Sarcasmo**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=sarcasmo) se ve que, aunque relacionados, no son sinónimos.

Comment: ¡Te damos la bienvenida al sitio! Ahora, en cuanto a tu respuesta, te invito a expandir un poco.  Por ejemplo, podrías incluir las partes relevantes de las páginas relevantes que encontraste.  También es útil dar ejemplos de situaciones donde un término o el otro sería más apto.  Puedes cliquear donde dice "edit" abajo de tu post.